# rehashing an input with openssl in mac os x versus linux

Tags: linux, mac, openssl, digest

I can run a command like the following in my script on linux:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 \
             -mac HMAC \
             -macopt hexkey:xxxx
```

But this command fails on mac os with the error

> unknown option '-mac'

I've tried sifting through man pages and online but I can't find any way to accomplish similar task using mac's version of openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of macOS is this? Older releases (10.11) have an old `openssl` that fails

```
$ /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
$ /usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:DEADBEEF
unknown option '-mac'
...
```

while newer (10.13) instead have LibreSSL that does not error out for your command. On older macs you could perhaps install `openssl` via a ports system (Fink, Homebrew, MacPorts).

Comment: Thank you - this was actually the problem.  I had installed a newer version on mac os 10.11.6 but it didn't update it

Comment: Let me correct my comment, the newer installed version wasn't updated at the default mac installed location.  I ended up having to link to the openssl in a different folder (brew installation), unfortunately mac os doesn't allow updating the symlinks and/or renaming the system installed version with a newer one.